# displaying 'Active' for a row which has 'A' as value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `course` and it has two columns `topic` and `status`..

There are three rows in the table..

```
('Computer','A')
('Science','I')
('History','A')
```

When displaying the values from the table I want to display `Active` for `A` and `Inactive` for `I`..   how can I do that... please help me here.

Comment: have a look a [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and see if you get any ideas

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT topic, 
       CASE status                     
         WHEN  'A' THEN 'Active'
         WHEN  'I' THEN 'Inactive'
       END
FROM course 
WHERE condition;
```

For general [case](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer have all pointed out the right approach for a query.  This answer is to explain how you can "bake" this directly into the table.  That is, you can store `'A'` and `'I'` in the field, but retrieve `'Active'` and `'Inactive'`.

For this, I'll rename the column in the table to `_status':

The first way is to use a view:

```
create view vw_table as 
    select <other columns>,
           (case when _status = 'A' then 'Active'
                 when _status = 'I' then 'Inactive'
            end) as status
    from t;
```

Then, your application code always uses the view and you are guaranteed that status is what you need. In SQL Server, you can also add a computed column in the table definition:

```
alter table
    add column status as (case when _status = 'A' then 'Active'
                               when _status = 'I' then 'Inactive'
                          end);
```

The advantage to using a view or computed column is that the spelling and definition are always the same.

Finally, often you want to turn such strings into a reference table.  In that case, you would actually have `statusID` in the original table, with the `status` table having the real definition.  For a binary value that has a clear definition, this might be overkill.  On the other hand, if you are learning SQL, this might be a good opportunity to learn about creating a reference table (and further normalizing your data structure).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Topic, 
    CASE Status  
        WHEN 'A' THEN 'Active' 
        WHEN 'I' THEN 'Inactive' 
        -- ELSE '' -- only if you need it
    END AS [Status]
FROM course
```

Answer (score 1):

Try CASE statement

```
select topic, 
case status when 'A' Then 'Active' WHen 'I' Then 'Inactive' END Status
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT ...,
  CASE ... WHEN ... THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive'
  ...
FROM table
```